# Gnome: workspaces don't survive monitor changes

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have a laptop monitor and a second monitor. On the second monitor, there are two workspaces. If I unplug the second monitor, everything appears on the laptop monitor. If I then plug in the second monitor again, everything returns to its previous state with my two workspaces and their windows intact. (That's how it's supposed to be)

However, the problem arises when I unplug my second monitor and connect another monitor (e.g., one at home versus one at work). In this case, there are no workspaces on the new monitor, and the windows are randomly distributed across the laptop screen and the new monitor.

Is there a way to transfer my workspaces from the second monitor to a new monitor?

Comment: That is probably something that needs to be solved by the software developpers. Gnome Shell "remembers" where the windows were, but if you then connect to a different monitor, the place where they were still is not available. I wonder whether one window, placed on your home monitor, would be restored on your home monitor after you had plugged in and out your work monitor (where it would not be restored).